# Do we have any code retrofit tools inbuilt for mainframe technologies like COBOL, JCL etc?

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl

I hope what does `retrofitting of code` mean?

> Since you checked-out the code from
>   prod, if any changes have been
>   deployed in prod, then retrofitting of
>   a code will add those changes to your
>   code to make your code deploy-ready.

Hope retrofitting is already known stuff. I know `SUPERCE` does in identifying the changes happened to code but do we have a tool which incorporated the changes automatically? Lemme know if you have a solution or question needs to be rephrased?

Comment: What is that sentence in gray? From some manual? Internal?

Comment: @belisarius on Dec26, That was a single sentenced brief description of what does retrofitting mean as per me. It was meant to give more scope to the person who wish to answer in case if he doesn't figure out my question. Did i make clear? please lemme know back...

Comment: @belisarius on Jan08: Hey I do these things except the last point. I don't browse questions regularly, but surely would check whenever i have question to post here. Apart from that I do vote, I do accept. Anyhow your suggestions will be followed, thanks and need always the same... nice day!

Comment: @Raja Thanks for your answer. I think perhaps you have some misconception about what voting is, because your profile states clearly that you never voted (although you accepted answers for 67% of your questions). Voting is done by pressing the gray triangles. If you DO vote and your voting score continues showing zero votes, I suggest to post this as a problem in Meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ because it may lessen your probability of getting good answers

Comment: And BTW, I never heard "code retrofit" in a mainframe environment, but as I always worked in non-English speaking companies, perhaps that is a language issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ISPF Editors "COMPARE" command.  It will merge the changes in as info lines and you can use the makedata (MD in the prefix area) command to accept the changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have never heard of them mentioned above. Do they come inbuilt with ISPF? please suggest me a source to know more on this...

Comment: The COMPARE command is built in to the ISPF Editor. Use PF1 or the command "HELP" and read the section on "EDIT PRIMARY COMMANDS" for more details.

Comment: yes! i came to know about this, but it doesnt help me in retrofitting the code. But i can say its good option to check the modifications happened since checkout... I want a retrofitting tool, which is capable of merging the changes with baseline before i stage it for deployment. Please lemme know if you are aware of such tools as well. Thanks!

Comment: Your source control should have an automated merge -- like CA-Endevors Parallel Development Manager (PDM).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is "Merge+Reconcile" from SERENA Software. It can compare up to 8 variations (derivatives) and uses an ISPF-editor like interface. If you're working on a huge merge, you may want to use its "Work In suspense" feature, where you save your intermediate results and come back on it at a later time to continue where you left of.

Refer to [page 15 of this PDF](http://www.serena.com/docs/repository/products/mainframe/Serena-Mainframe-Brochure.pdf) for way more details.

Answer (score 0):

My this has aged. When in parallel development (say multi year projects with multiple major releases in the pipeline).

The retrofit occurs when an accepted and implemented change needs to be shoehorned into the other arms, where code may not be identical prior to the change. It may not possible to automate.

Comment: ...and ask why your shop did not buy Endevor.  There is also Windiff and superc on Wintel. In GNU these changes might be called backports, but really it is reconciliation. Just about anyone reading here should  understand "staged" development and "parallel" development and forking considerations.